# How do I enable Grails support in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 9.0 BETA?

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

The IntelliJ Groovy/Grails support in IntelliJ IDEA 8.1 is great.

However, I've recently upgraded to the new and recently open-sourced IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 9.0 BETA. Since updating to the new version the Grails support seems to have disappeared. I'm no longer able to choose the option "Grails application" when creating a new project.

My question is simply:

- How do I enable Grails support in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Grails is not supported in the community edition. You can see what is and is not supported [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).